# Method Returning incorrect value

Tags: groovy, selenium, iteration, return-value

If I call findEventWithStatus("Comment","Completed") instead of returning a single event it returns the entire list of events generated by the getEvents() method. Why is this so? Applicable code is below.

Definition of the Event object:-

```
class Event {
    String description
    String date
    String status
    WebElement editEvent
    WebElement deleteEvent
}
```

Get the events from the HTML table using selenium:-

```
def getEvents() {
    def eventSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath('//div[@id[contains(.,"eventsReviewTable")]]/table/tbody/tr')).size()
    def eventList = new ArrayList()
    def event = new Event()
    def x
    for (y in 0..eventSize-1) {
        x = (y+1).toString()
        event.date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id[contains(.,'eventsReviewTable')]]/table/tbody/tr["+ x + "]/td[1]/div/span")).getText()
        event.description = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id[contains(.,'eventsReviewTable')]]/table/tbody/tr["+ x + "]/td[2]/div/span")).getText()
        event.status = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id[contains(.,'eventsReviewTable')]]/table/tbody/tr["+ x + "]/td[4]/div/span")).getText()
        event.editEvent =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id[contains(.,'eventsReviewTable')]]/table/tbody/tr["+ x + "]/td[6]/div/a[@id[contains(.,'editEventLink')]]"))
        event.deleteEvent =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id[contains(.,'eventsReviewTable')]]/table/tbody/tr["+ x + "]/td[6]/div/a[@id[contains(.,'deleteEventLink')]]"))
        eventList.add(event)
        event = new Event()
    }
    return eventList
}
```

Finding an event with a specific status and description:-

```
def findEventWithStatus(String desc, String status) {
    def events = getEvents()
    events.each() {
        if(it.description == desc && it.status == status) {
             return it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `return it` from the `findEventWithStatus` method is returning from the closure passed to `event.each` instead of returning from the `findEventWithStatus` method. So, the `each` method is not doing anything really, and as `each` returns the collection in which it was invoked, it is returning the `events` value, which is what is finally being returned from `findEventWithStatus` as the `events.each { ... }` is the last statement in that method. I hope that wasn't too confusing hehe.

Anyway, it can be fixed using a `for` statement instead of `each`, but, as you are searching for an object, the [`find`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method will work much better:

```
def findEventWithStatus(String desc, String status) {
    getEvents().find { it.description == desc && it.status == status }
}
```